# SELECT and UPDATE row concurrently

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE user(
    username VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    quantity INT NOT NULL
);
```

I need to access the sum of every value in the `quantity` column frequently and prevent every insert after it reaches 10000, but can't use `SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM user;` since the `user` table could contain thousands of records.

I came up with the following solution:

Define a `user_sum` table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_sum(
    sum INT
);
```

Define a `do_sum()` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION do_sum() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE sum_result INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT sum INTO sum_result FROM user_sum;
    sum_result = NEW.quantity + sum_result;
    IF sum_result > 10000 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'LIMIT_REACHED';
    END IF;
    UPDATE user_sum SET sum = sum_result;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Define a `sum_trigger`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sum_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON user
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE do_sum();
```

This approach works fine until multiple inserts in the `user` are done concurrently.

What's the most efficient way to solve this?

Comment: Have a check constraint in the user_sum table, allowing only a sum of up to 10000. Then don't do anything but increase the sum in the user_sum table in the trigger .

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Add some reasoning, and it will make a good answer.

Comment: What happens if a user is deleted? Even trickier user.sum is updated.